# awk store a pattern result to a shell array variable

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to store the result of a pattern matched by awk to a shell  array variable. Here's a simplified example of the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array1=()
declare -a array2=()
READ_FILE="directory1/read_file.csv"
WRITE_FILE="directory2/results.csv"

#variable for counting array index
count1=0
count2=0
#
#
# need help with line below
# $2 below is the second set of characters which is a floating point number
awk -F 'string1_to_search' '{$array1[count1++] = $2}' $READ_FILE >> $WRITE_FILE
awk -F 'string2_to_search' '{$array2[count1++] = $2}' $READ_FILE >> $WRITE_FILE
#count++ indicates post increment of count variable
```

any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not write to Bash variables from inside `awk`.

What you should do instead is to make `awk` print out everything you want to store in the array, one item per line, and then use the Bash built-in `mapfile` to read it into an array:

```bsh
mapfile -t array1 < <( awk -F 'string1_to_search' '{print $2}' "$READ_FILE" )
```

After that, your array is in `$array1`. You also don't need to `declare` it beforehand, `mapfile` does that for you.

More information about `mapfile` can be found by typing `help mapfile`.

<sub>**Side note:**

I used redirected process substitution `mapfile ... < <( awk ... )` here instead of a pipe <del>`awk ... | mapfile ...`</del>, because you can not use `mapfile` as part of a pipeline. This is because pipelines are executed in subshells, which do not propagate their changed variables back to the parent shell, i.e. the value of `myarray` would be lost.</sub>

Comment: What if the value sent to the array is a number ? I am trying to do reduction operation on the array element but I get an error and  to me it seems like the element is parsed as a string rather than a number

Comment: To my knowledge Bash does not differentiate between strings and numbers in variables/arrays, everything is treated as a string. Just commands may try to interpret those strings as numbers. Could you give more detail about what you are trying to do, like the actual commands, and also double-check the content of the array for correctness? Maybe you should also ask this in a new follow-up question, where you can add a link to this one for context. If you leave me a comment here once you posted it, I'll go and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For example when you want the output of

```
awk -f TableParser.awk table.txt
```

to be read as a variable in shell script, just write the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

mapfile -t var1 < <( awk -f TableParser.awk table.txt )
echo $var1
```